# MySQL 5.7 (Percona Server) PAM LDAP authentication from Workbench 8.0 on Windows

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona, ldap

I have a server running Percona Server 5.7 and enabled PAM LDAP authentication.
I can connect with LDAP user from:

- mysql client
- MySQL Workbench 8.0 on Linux (Ubuntu) with `dialog.so` plugin copied from Percona Server 8.0 distribution.
- MySQL Workbench 6.3 on Windows with `dialog.dll` plugin copied from MariaDB 10.5 distribution to this path: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib\plugin`

But, I can not make it work with MySQL Workbench 8.0 on Windows.
With Procmon I can see that the plugin is expected to be found at: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin`, but when I copy the `dialog.dll` file I get
Error: `Authentication plugin 'dialog' can not be loaded: Incompatible client plugin interface`

I have tried with `dialog.dll` file from MariaDB 10.2 - 10.5 distributions, none of them seems to work. I have tried also with the `dialog.dll` file from HeidiSQL distribution, but that one doesn't work either.
Percona doesn't have distribution for Windows.

Anyone have some solution?

Comment: You may find this 2017 URL helpful from Percona about Windows implementation - https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/14/run-percona-server-on-bash-on-windows-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks, but as I can see on the link the post doesn't have any information about PAM, LDAP, Workbench or the `dialog.dll` plugin, so it is not useful.